# Best way to lock entities between clients

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, file-io, locking

We are re-writing an old Cobol application in Java EE.
The old Cobol is a full client application.

The client's requirement is to lock entities (e.g. a particular account) so that no one can access it or at least only in read-only. This is because some transactions might be long and we don't want users to enter a lot of data just to loose everything while updating.
Optimistic locking is not wanted.

Currently the requirement is implemented by creating locks in a file system with a lot of problems like concurrent access, no transactions. Not very Java EE compliant.
The lock should also tell the client that is locking an entity.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the database itself for locking instead of the file system approach.

In an application we implemented locking an an per entity basis by using a special table LOCK which had the fields ENTITY_TYPE, ENTITY_ID, USER_ID and VALID_TO. Locks created timed out after a certain time when the user did not do anything. This was to prevent locked entities which can never be edited by other users when a client closes the application or due to network errors etc.

Before allowing a user to edit an entity we checked / created a row in this table. On the UI the user had a button to lock an entity or an info box showing the user holding the lock if an entity was already locked.